# T-distribution problem

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, t-distribution

I am working through the exercises of Martin Sternstein's Statistics (Barron's College Review Series) ... struggling with Exercise 4 in Chapter 14.

Given are the weight lifting strengths of 9 people before/after 8 weeks of weight lifting exercises: Before: 3,3.5,4,6,7,8,8.5,12.5,15. After: 7,17,19,12,19,22,28,20,28.

Asked is to construct the 95% CI a) before training strength, b) after training strength and c) strength gain.

The answers are given at the back of the book as follows: a) 7.5 +- 2.262(4.085/sqrt(9)) b) 19.11 +- 2.262(6.791/sqrt(9)) and c) 11.61 +- 2.262(4.891/sqrt(9)).

My struggles:

a) given n=9, I thought df=8 and looked up 2.5% (due to two-sided) and got critical value of 2.306, but the book's answer uses 2.262 which corresponds to df=9. Anyone know why?

b) I understand both 4.085/sqrt(9) and 6.791/sqrt(9) for a) and b) but not the 4.891/sqrt(9). I had sqrt(4.085^2/9 + 6.79^2/9). Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have added the self-study tag and read the wiki. And this is not homework. I am 50 year old engineer working in Lean Six Sigma and using the mentioned book to refresh my college knowledge from 25+ years ago.

Comment: Not sure what more I can add to explain what I have done and where I'm stuck. The calculations of the means are fine but the look-up of the critical value is one problem where I was using a different value from the book's answer.

Comment: Second ... calculating the CI of the difference (gain) between after and before, I get the correct central value, but here I also used the df=8 critical value instead of the df=9 which the book uses and for the stdev i was using what i wrote in the last line of the original post whereas the book uses 4.891 which I dont know how they got to.

Comment: 95% CI before: $(4.36, 10.64),$ rounded to two places. After: $( 13.89, 24.33).$ Gain: $( 7.85, 15.37).$ See if you can get similar answers from formulas in your text. // It seems you're right about DF. If the answer book has a mistake, it would certainly not be the first time for such a thing to happen. My answers from R. // If you have trouble, post the specifics of what you tried.// For Gain you have to use a **one-sample** t interval for the nine differences. (Not a 2-sample procedure.) // Quantiles .025 & .075  of T(8) from R are 'qt(c(.025, .975), 8)': $-2.306004  ,  2.306004,$ resp.

Comment: I got standard deviations 4.085034, 6.790516, and 4.891177.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for the replies. Your idea of using R prompted me to use Minitab (silly me ... I not think of it before). And that indeed confirms the df should be 8 and the answer in the book is incorrect.

Comment: The other mistake I made is to interpret the "95% CI for the gain" as a paired t-test, which for the purpose of the 95%CI is not needed. Like you said, the exercise was basically to create 3 one-sample t-tests. Thanks again for your help and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may still be puzzled by the CI for gain.
You have paired data. You need to start by getting the nine gains, and then
do a ***one-sample CI*** using those nine values.

Here is a bit of R code that computes the CI directly
and then again as part of the `t.test` procedure in R.

```
g = a-b
g
[1]  4.0 13.5 15.0  6.0 12.0 14.0 19.5  7.5 13.0

mean(g); sd(g)
[1] 11.61111
[1] 4.891177
qt(c(.025,.975),8)
[1] -2.306004  2.306004

CI = mean(d) + qt(c(.025,.975), 8)* sd(g)/3;  CI
[1]  7.85142 15.37080

t.test(g)$conf.int
[1]  7.85142 15.37080
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```